# Linking GitHub to project

Tags: git, github, cmd, init

On my Cmd interface, i input the command git init in the directory of my folder to link but the cmd return Git is not recognized as an internal or external command

Please what should i try next?

Comment: Git is not installed on your computer. Or it can't find the git command in your environment path.

Comment: Did `git init` fail or did the command `git remote add` not work on your command prompt? I presume you are using git bash?
Did you get an error message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Git bash(https://gitforwindows.org/). You have to install this, and use the Git Bash for do git stuffs.